# How can we convert a Bitmap into an image OR store into a Variable?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I am making an android application in which I am showing image from internet into a `ImageView` by help of these classes

1. MemoryCache
2. ImageLoader
3. FileCache
4. Utils

In my main class I am calling this method `imgLoader.DisplayImage(strURL, loader, image);` to show the image and It is working really very fine and I think The four classes which I have mentioned above are common may be people know about that (If you don't then [here's the code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/)) 
Now I want this method to call in `AsyncTask` class method `doInBackground()`
how can I do this.
And here is what I am doing is:

```
protected ImageView doInBackground(String...args)
            {
            try 
                {
                imgLoader.DisplayImage(strURL, loader, image);
                }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } ;
                return image;
            }
```

I know that it is completely wrong we can not pass an image as `ImageView` please help me how can I return the image from this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're going to be loading an image in a background thread via an async, just store the image url to a string and update your views in the `onPostExecute(void..)` function

Honestly though, I wouldn't use imageLoader for anything. I've used it before and it has limitations. Picasso is a much better way to cache and load images. Faster as well.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Lmk if you have anymore questions!

Comment: I am really very thankful to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: no problem! If I helped solve your problem, could you mark my answer as accepted? Thank you!

Comment: yeah I never knew about accept button sorry thanks a lot man.

Comment: Is this working in background mean will not affect the processes coded after that in main activity.

Comment: an asyncTask is basically a way to do concurrent processing. If you run your async task, it will do all its work on a background thread and free up the Main UI thread. Which is what we want. it doesn't mean it won't affect processes after you call it. It's a process running by itself in the background. There's tons of docs on AsyncTask and services. I'll link one for each:
https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Yeah I read it and what does <data types> after AsyncTask means, I mean where I am going to use them

Comment: Good question. You can map them to the return types of what your functions will return. if you say AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
Then your doInBackground() function will need to return a string.

Comment: is void no. 1 for onpreexecute() and void no.2 for onpostexecute() ?

Comment: Params – the input. what you pass to the AsyncTask

Progress – if you have any updates, passed to onProgressUpdate()

Result – the output. what returns doInBackground()

This information is in the article I gave you.

Comment: Not able to write that line neither in doInBackground() nor in onPostExecute() . It is giving error with with(this) saying not applicable for argument (main.Backgound)